How do I create/update/retrieve multiple Models in one View in Django Rest Framework
I have a Business model and Order model. Businesses can order furniture in our website. A user creates an account and makes an order. Since he is a new user, he is not associated to any Business. In the order form, he will give the information about his business and some information related to current order. A new Business record and Order record will be created with the given info. There's a foreign key for Business in Order table.
If he wants to create a second order, since he has already a business, he will have the business info pre-filled in his form. When he gives the order data and submits, backend won't create a new Business record. It only creates Order record and store the Business reference.
How do I achieve this in single endpoint to create update and retrieve?

# models.py

class Order(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='Applicant', blank=True, null=True)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='Business', blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name='Order Code', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    chairs = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Chairs', blank=True, null=True)
    tables = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Tables', blank=True, null=True)
    delivery_type = models.CharField(verbose_name='Delivery Type', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_type = models.CharField(verbose_name='Payment Type', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('CREATED', 'Created'),
        ('IN_PROGRESS', 'In Progress'),
        ('CANCELLED', 'Cancelled'),
        ('SHIPPED', 'Shipped'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True, default='CREATED')


class Business(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Legal Name', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name='Business Code', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.CharField(verbose_name='Website URL', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(verbose_name="Street Address 1", blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name='City', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(verbose_name='State', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(verbose_name='Country', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)



# serializers.py

import time



class BusinessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = '__all__'
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        timestamp = int(time.time())
        random_number = random.randint(100,999)
        validated_data['code'] = f'BUSINESS-{timestamp}'
        validated_data['status'] = 'CREATED'
        return super().create(validated_data)

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        timestamp = int(time.time())
        random_number = random.randint(100,999)
        validated_data['code'] = f'ORDER-{timestamp}'
        validated_data['status'] = 'CREATED'
        return super().create(validated_data)

# views.py

class BusinessOrderAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):

        business_data = self.request.data.get('business', {})
        business_id = business.get('id')
        if business_id:
            try:
                business = Business.objects.get(pk=business_id)
            except Business.DoesNotExist:
                business = Business.objects.create()
            business.name = business_data.get('name')
            business.website = business_data.get('website')
            business.address = business_data.get('address')
            business.city = business_data.get('city')
            business.state = business_data.get('state')
            business.country = business_data.get('country')
            business.save()

            order = serializer.save(business=business.pk)


This is how my request would look
{
    
    "chairs": 3,
    "tables": 1,
    "delivery_type": "ONE_DAY",
    "payment_type": "CASH_ON_DELIVERY",
    "business": {
        "name": "Vin.AI",
        "website": "https://lol.com",
        "address": "My street",
        "city": "Gotham City",
        "state": "New York",
        "country": "USA",
    }
}

This is the response I'm getting
{
    "business": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict."
    ]
}


Share your models.

@Niko added models

The problem is simple. Your serializer expects business field as a PK not as a dict as you are sending in your payload. Yet, to perform the required action some work is necessary. Also, the models are also a bit odd, but I will not get into that in depth.
Currently, the Business model has no field that could relate an User to it. Meaning that, you will know who made the Order but never who created the Business.
Based on what you said, I suppose that a Business belongs to an User and only one. (Of course you can easily modify that with a one-to-many relation).
So starting with a minor modification to your models, remove applicant from Order and add to Business (the owner I guess):
class Business(models.Model):
    applicant = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        primary_key=True
    )
    ...

Also, there is a minor mistake on BusinessSerializer, there is no field called status, remove the line:
class BusinessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...
        # validated_data["status"] = "CREATED"
        return super().create(validated_data)

There is more than one approach to this problem. But to keep things simple:

Check if the current User has a Business
If not we create one given the payload data

class BusinessOrderAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    business_serializer = BusinessSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_business = None
        try:
            user_business = request.user.business

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            business = request.data.pop("business")
            business["applicant"] = request.user.pk
            business_serializer = self.business_serializer(data=business)
            business_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            user_business = business_serializer.save()

        request.data["business"] = user_business.pk
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(
            serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers
        )

You could adapt this code in several forms. In case you want to keep the original format just use try/except to query a Business given some unique identifier (such as the name or website).
